# MVC5 Strange bahavior of User.IsInRole in layout and controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I've got some strange issue and I can't figure it out. I've got a login form in a view. This view is rendered inside layout. In this layout I use User.IsInRole("roleName") to custom it depending on current users role. It works ok.

There's a Login action in my project (building from mvc template) with statement "var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...)".I check value of "result". If it equals SignInStatus.Success I use User.IsInRole("roleName") to determine users role and redirect him to some other action. And here's a problem. User.IsInRole("roleName") returns false. User.IsAuthenticated is also false. Why is that? How to deal with this situation?

I just want to redirect user to a specific action - each type of user has its own first page so I need to determine user role after he logs in.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you post some code??

Comment: It's weird how some things you just never come across despite how long you've worked with a particular language/framework. I don't know for sure, but it's possible that the `User` object in the controller is not updated until the next request, so even though you've signed them in, the `User` is still unauthenticated. It would be better for this, I think, if you looked up the user from the database and queried the roles off that instance.

Comment: It's weird. I wanted to check if this whole situation is my fault. I created new project based on mvc tamplate. Then I tried to get current user in Login action. The problem still exists. The question is why.

Comment: One more thing: If I log in successfully and leave Login action I can use User instance in other actions. The user is authenticated in these actions.

Answer (score 0):

Internally at some point the real work of `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...)` calls `AuthenticationManager.SignIn`. Looking at the spec for this we see this comment...

```
// Summary:
//     Add information to the response environment that will cause the appropriate
//     authentication middleware to grant a claims-based identity to the recipient
//     of the response. The exact mechanism of this may vary.  Examples include
//     setting a cookie, to adding a fragment on the redirect url, or producing
//     an OAuth2 access code or token response.
```

My take on this is that the reason you can't query Roles, check authorization, or pretty much anything dealing with claims or identities is because the request doesn't have that information setup yet until a response containing the identity is first sent back to the client.

To accomplish what you want to do, just follow Chris Pratt's idea and query the DB for the roles instead of the identity.